# Java addActionListener isn't Working on Certain Buttons

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

I've been working on a project and here is what i do . i get data from a Database and put them in an array of Objects that are JPanels with some edits . So here is The problem . back in the Main Program i wrote a loop so that it add actionlisteners to the buttons in these JPanels . Yet it doesn't work.

```
package testgen;

import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class TestGen extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

private static JPanel container;
private static StudentIntro p2;
private static MainPanel p1;
private static InstructorIntro p3;
private final CardLayout cards;
private boolean isValid;
private final DBHandler DB;
private QPanel[] panels = new QPanel[10];
private final LoadingPanel n = new LoadingPanel();

public TestGen() {
    DB = new DBHandler();
    this.cards = new CardLayout();
    container = new JPanel();
    container.setLayout(cards);
    p1 = new MainPanel();
    p2 = new StudentIntro();
    p3 = new InstructorIntro();

    container.add(p1, "mainPanel");
    container.add(p2, "studentPanel");
    container.add(p3, "instructorPanel");
    container.add(n, "loading");

    p1.goNext.addActionListener(this);
    p2.back.addActionListener(this);
    p2.start.addActionListener(this);
    n.startTest.addActionListener(this);

    cards.show(container, "1");

}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    TestGen c = new TestGen();
    c.add(container);
    c.setSize(650, 550);
    c.setResizable(false);
    c.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    c.setVisible(true);
    c.setTitle(" Fist Bump Quiz Generator");
    c.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

}

private boolean checkValid(MainPanel p) {
    String id = p.getId();
    if (id.isEmpty()) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid ID or Password!", "Try Again", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
        return false;
    }

    String sql = "SELECT passwords FROM `instructors` WHERE username ='" + id + "'";
    if (DB.checkConn() == false) {

        return false;
    }
    String right = DB.fetchPassword(sql);
    char[] password = p.getPassword();
    String inPass = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < password.length; i++) {
        inPass = inPass + password[i];
    }

    if (right.equals(inPass) == false) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid ID or Password!", "Try Again", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
        return false;
    }

    return true;

}

private void addListners() {
    addL();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

        container.add(panels[i], "question" + (i + 1));

        if (i == 0) {
            if (panels[i].getQuesType().equals("TF")) {
                ((TFPanel) panels[i]).goPrev.setEnabled(false);
            } else if (panels[i].getQuesType().equals("Blank")) {
                ((FillBlank) panels[i]).goPrev.setEnabled(false);
            } else {
                ((ShortAns) panels[i]).goPrev.setEnabled(false);
            }

        }

        if (i == 9) {
            if (panels[i].getQuesType().equals("TF")) {
                ((TFPanel) panels[i]).goNext.setText("Submit Test");
            } else if (panels[i].getQuesType().equals("Blank")) {
                ((FillBlank) panels[i]).goNext.setText("Submit Test");
            } else {
                ((ShortAns) panels[i]).goNext.setText("Submit Test");
            }

        }

    }
}

private void quesPopulate() {
    Runnable r = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (DB.checkConn(false) == true) {
                cards.show(container, "loading");
            }
            return;
        }
    };
    Thread t = new Thread(r);
    t.start();

    Runnable r2 = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (DB.checkConn() == true) {
                panels = DB.fetchQuestion();
                addListners();
                n.startTest.setVisible(true);
                n.loadimg.setVisible(false);

            }
        }
    };
    Thread t2 = new Thread(r2);

    t2.start();

}

private void addL() {

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        switch (panels[i].getQuesType()) {
            case "TF":
                ((TFPanel) panels[i]).goPrev.addActionListener(this);
                ((TFPanel) panels[i]).goNext.addActionListener(this);
                System.out.println("Action Added " + i);
                break;
            case "Blank":
                ((FillBlank) panels[i]).goPrev.addActionListener(this);
                ((FillBlank) panels[i]).goNext.addActionListener(this);
                System.out.println("Action Added " + i);
                break;
            case "Short":
                ((ShortAns) panels[i]).goPrev.addActionListener(this);
                ((ShortAns) panels[i]).goNext.addActionListener(this);
                System.out.println("Action Added " + i);
                break;
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    try {
        if (e.getSource() == p1.goNext && p1.goNext.isEnabled() && "Login".equals(p1.goNext.getText())) {
            isValid = checkValid(p1);

            if (isValid) {
                cards.show(container, "instructorPanel");

            }

        } else if (e.getSource() == p1.goNext && p1.goNext.isEnabled() && p1.goNext.getText().equals("Get Started!")) {
            try {
                if (p1.getName().isEmpty()) {
                    throw new RuntimeException();

                } else {
                    cards.show(container, "studentPanel");
                    p2.setLabel(p1.getName());
                }

            } catch (Exception ex) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please Enter your Name", "Try Again", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
            }

        } else if (e.getSource() == p2.back) {
            cards.show(container, "mainPanel");

        } else if (e.getSource() == n.startTest) {

            System.out.println("button Pressed");
            cards.show(container, "question2");

        } else if (e.getSource() == p2.start) {
            Runnable r2 = new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    quesPopulate();

                }
            };

            Thread t2 = new Thread(r2);
            t2.start();

            Runnable r = new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {

                    addListners();

                }
            };
            Thread t = new Thread(r);

        } else if (e.getSource() == ((TFPanel) panels[9]).goNext) {
            int finals = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
                panels[j].checkAnswer();
                if (panels[j].isScore() == true) {
                    finals++;
                }

            }

            System.out.println(finals);
        } else {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                if (panels[i].getQuesType().equals("TF")) {
                    System.out.println("button Pressed");
                    if (e.getSource() == ((TFPanel) panels[i]).goPrev) {
                        cards.show(container, "question" + (i));
                    } else if (e.getSource() == ((TFPanel) panels[i]).goNext) {
                        cards.show(container, "question" + (i + 2));
                    }
                } else if (panels[i].getQuesType().equals("Blank")) {
                    System.out.println("button Pressed");
                    if (e.getSource() == ((FillBlank) panels[i]).goPrev) {
                        cards.show(container, "question" + (i));
                    } else if (e.getSource() == ((FillBlank) panels[i]).goNext) {
                        cards.show(container, "question" + (i + 2));
                    }

                } else if (panels[i].getQuesType().equals("Short")) {
                    System.out.println("button Pressed");
                    if (e.getSource() == ((ShortAns) panels[i]).goPrev) {
                        cards.show(container, "question" + (i));
                    } else if (e.getSource() == ((ShortAns) panels[i]).goNext) {
                        cards.show(container, "question" + (i + 2));
                    }

                }

            }
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {

    }

}
```

}
Edit ( Added formatted Full class ) i can't provide a runnable Program as it have multiple classes . also i am using ActionListener from outside the panel class because i need to switch the card layout upon a button Press.
any Help in that case ? Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: Please fix your code's formatting, especially its indentation. Your indentation is all over the place, and you've got excessive empty lines making your code hard to read, and if it's hard to read, it's hard to understand. Myself, I would avoid using a single ActionListener for many varied buttons and instead would try to use custom listeners/Actions for each class of functionality.

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: Don't call `addListners` from outside of the EDT

Comment: You're ignoring any possible exceptions, which is always a bad idea

Comment: @MadProgrammer Noted !! :D removed that and gave me the stacktrace . Fixed ! :D Didn't really notice that i still have a try and catch around that :D . Really Thank you ! :)